# How to restrict file upload size in AWS Application Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, load-balancing

Is is possible to restrict the file upload size (of an http post request) at an AWS Application Load Balancer?

I want in general to restrict the upload size of a file, but I don't want the request to get to the web servers if the file size is too big. I am assuming my thinking is right in that rejecting the request earlier on gives better protection against DoS attacks, and in general will reduce the load on the web servers (thereby reducing costs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly on ALB itself. However, you can associate [Web Application Firewall](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-chapter.html) with it.

With WAF you can setup [size constraint rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-size-constraint-match.html) on your ALB. This way you can block large requests hitting your web-servers.

Comment: I am not sure this answer is correct .as the link you reference is only checking the uri size of a request and not the actual payload. AWS WAF has a limitation that it can only inspect the first 8kb of the request body.